# I started rendering a new animation after completely rendering one before. How do I retrieve that older render?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

This has happened multiple times, but I would render an image or animation, but would accidentally re-render the image or animation.

How do I go to the UV image editor and find the older render?

Comment: Once you've overwritten the old render, there's not much you can do.. There are some practices you can get into to prevent this from happening though

Comment: @gandalf3 is refering to rendering to other slots, I think

Comment: Screw my life either which way. Blender crashed on me which crashed my PC and lost all seven hours of the render anyways.

Comment: That sucks :/ In future, you can save the animation frames to a different folder on your PC (don't use the C:/tmp default)

Comment: I know I was also trying to figure that out too like I rendered it but where do I save it? Do I have to compile the png files together to make the avi? Then it crashed. Sadly.

Answer (score 3):

If you wrote over other files there isn't much you can do other than doing some kind of forensics and trying to recover your files with Data Recovery software (and that is way beyond the scope of this site).

On the other hand there are a couple of things you should do to prevent this from happening again:

-. Uncheck the Overwrite box on the output tab.

[image]

-. Don't use an animation (AVI, Qucktime, h264, Xvid, MPEG) format as output.

-. Render your animation as a series of images (PNG, Tiff, DPX, OpenEXR) and compile as video once you have rendered all your frames. This way, if the computer crashes you'll only loose the current frame but will keep all of the frames that have been rendered already.

-. Save different image sequence/animation renders to different folders under the Output file-path. This will let you save newly rendered sequences while preserving older ones for later analysis.